# java - a nonstatic field inside a static class

Tags: java

It's my first time coming across such pattern of code, it might be fairly familiar to advanced gurus out there:

```
public static class Myclass{
    public static class myChildClass{
        public int a =1;   //this doesn't give an error although I expected it should be declared static
    }
}
```

I can't instantiate the static inner class and I can't access the variable `int a` outside the class, so does this variable become private to the class? Why does java allow this instead of complaining it be declared static?

Comment: "this doesn't give an error" This isn't valid code: you'd get an error elsewhere.

Comment: "I can't instantiate the static inner class" why not?

Comment: @AndyTurner , I can't instantiate a static class because by definition there's no instance of a static class... i suppose? let's even consider when Myclass is also static

Comment: @Sheri, thanks edited ti

Comment: @AndyTurner , "you'd get an error elsewhere"? where is elsewhere? Android studio doesn't throw any error during build

Comment: I think you misunderstand what a static class is: it's merely a nested class without an implicit reference to an instance of the enclosing class that created it. You can create an instance of it - just try it.

Comment: I made that comment before you [edited it to add the `class` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/60996931/1) on the nested class.

Comment: @AndyTurner , I edited it further

Comment: Revision 2 is fine, Revision 1 and 3 don't compile. Java has, unlike C#, no concept of a static class (no instances allowed). In Java, such a thing is usually archived by only having one private constructor.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn "static inner class" is a contradiction in terms. [Inner classes are not static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). Perhaps you mean "static nested class".

Comment: Java has inner classes and static nested classes. A inner class requires an instance of it's enclosing type to create. A nested class does not have this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't instantiate the static inner class

Of course you can:

```
Myclass.myChildclass m = new Myclass.myChildclass();
```

> and I can't access the variable int a outside the class

Yes you can:

```
System.out.println(m.a);
```

> so does this variable become private to the class?

No, because it's not private.

> Why does java allow this instead of complaining it be declared static?

I think you misunderstand what a static class is: it's merely a nested class without an implicit reference to an instance of the enclosing class that created it. There is no requirement for its members to be static.

Comment: If we can't instantiate a static class, why can we instantiate a static inner class of a static class?

Comment: @juztcode "If we can't instantiate a static class" we can, so the rest of your question is moot. (Also "static inner class" is a contradiction in terms).

Comment: @juztcode there's no `static` vs `static inner` class, there's just a class that is declared as a static variable of an other class. It's just another class like the others

Comment: [C# has static classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members). Java does not have something similar. You can prevent the instantiation by creating a private constructor (that is never called), see for example [`java.lang.System`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/29d878d3af35/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/System.java#l105).

Comment: @AndyTurner , I thought java was similar to other languages, but as Johannes pointed out it's not the case. Then what is the significance of static class? It has an option to not be instantiated?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn , other languages like C++ also do not have instantiable static class like java does or do they? (If you're familiar with C++) if so, what is the use of such static class, why not just create a non static class?

Comment: @juztcode it's a nested class that you don't need to have an instance of the enclosing class to create. That's all. This is commonly used for helper classes such as Builders, where it wouldn't make sense to have an instance of the thing you're trying to construct in order to construct the thing to construct it.

Comment: @juztcode C++ is not Java. Help yourself by freeing yourself from the idea that "it's called the same thing, so it *must be* the same thing". (For example, C++ and Java both have references, but these aren't the same thing at all).

Comment: @AndyTurner , okay so, one last confirmation, instance classes have copies of variable for themselves and static variables are global to the class irrespective of how many instances created, but if you instantiate a static class and change the variable value, then, you change the variable value ... for the class? Then how would we emulate the essense of static(as in C++) variable in java?

Comment: @juztcode are you asking how to declare a static member variable? You declare it `static`.

Comment: @AndyTurner , but how is that static? Since I can make instance of the static class, it would be `static` to that instant? but that's not static at all, is it? Isn't it rather like 3 instances should refer to the same variable and value?

Comment: it seems it is the  case, I experimented it out, changing an instant variable of the so called "static class" changes all instance variables, but it seems nested classes work as namespaces do in C++